# Help to solve a circuit with capacitor and resistor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

Till now I'd never solved a circuit with resistor and capacitor. I'd seen the problem and tried to solve. But now I am in a doubt.The circuit was like that-[image: Resistors and capacitors are in one circuit]

My attempt-

Comment: Do you have any information about the frequency of the supply? Is it the standard 50Hz or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming steady state means that you have no current flowing in the branch with capacitors in it.

So think of the circuit first as a potential divider made up of the battery and the two resistors.
From this you can find the potential difference across the two capacitors.